# File does not exists in stack trace

Tags: php, php-7, stack-trace

I'm using php7.0.33 in a Debian docker. It's using php-fpm and an nginx server to server php content.

When I'm requesting the server, I have a crash with a stack trace :

```
Stack trace:
#0 [internal function]: php\Boot::php\{closure}(2, 'file_get_conten...', '/var/www/htdocs...', 29, Array)
#1 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sys/io/File.php(29): file_get_contents('/var/www/htdocs...')
#2 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/i18n/Locale.php(51): sys\io\File::getBytes('/var/www/htdocs...')
#3 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(427): sugoi\i18n\Locale::init('fr')
#4 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(840): sugoi\BaseApp->initLang('fr')
#5 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(531): sugoi\BaseApp->setupLang()
#6 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(160): sugoi\BaseApp->mainLoop()
#7 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(744): sugoi\BaseApp->cloneApp()
#8 /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/BaseApp.php(103): sugoi\BaseApp->run()
#9 /var/www/htdocs/lib/App.php(169): sugoi\BaseApp::main()
```

The problem is I've already fixed that bug.

I've even removed the `/var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/i18n/Locale.php` file **inside the docker container**, but the stack trace remains the same.

```
root@dock:/# cat /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/i18n/Locale.php
cat: /var/www/htdocs/lib/sugoi/i18n/Locale.php: No such file or directory
```

I've restarted both nginx and php-fpm, but still, the stack traces stays exactly the same. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Did you rebuild your docker image with new changes?

Comment: Yes I did, but I always made the modifications directly inside the docker image just to be safe.

Comment: the docker container* I mean

Comment: Can it be that this file is auto-generated? Try deleting docker container and rebuilding it, check if file still exists on initial setup